# why does this system freeze if I run any user other than root? (gdm, xdm, lxdm, etc)

Tags: kernel, freeze

I'm on an old desktop (see the hardinfo report): [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/240188/hardinfo_report.html)

Okay, the problem I have is, I'm forced to use root (which is not safe, obviously) to do anything! I can't log in as a user (except from a terminal), which is **very** bad, because I'm not the person who needs to use this system, *and* because we need to use wine to recover critical data. Basically... I need to find out where the freezing is coming from. noapci, noacpi, nomodeset, etc... don't make a difference to the situation. I can't tell if it's a kernel bug, because all that I can tell indicates that, but somehow it seems unrelated (I mean, startx works as root!).

Any ideas? I really need to get this working **urgently** for the person who needs to use it, to recover very **critical** data, and as we are not able to buy a new system... you get the point. Our previously working desktop got fried by Hurricane Tomas.

**EDIT** We gave up hope on this system... it start freezing under root, so we're going to try to backup the data to an external drive (if we can keep the system active long enough, or with a live CD) and try to recover the information from the databases etc on another system. Not the best solution, but the only one we have.

Comment: What happens if you create a new user, delete everything in their home directory, and then try to log in as that user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly have no idea why this is happening, but you can easily recover critical data by using a Live CD to mount your hard drive, and then you can copy any important files to a flash drive.

Comment: I actually have an external HDD that we can copy to, but the reason we wanted to recover this system (we gave up now) was cause it would make it much more simple for us to have the system running to access the data on it (it's complicated), and a live cd won't be the best bet because of the limited RAM (it's slow, and there are minor risks involved).

Answer (score 0):

we gave up. system is freezing as root now as well, possibly the disk/memory/processor is faulty. going to try a last resort option. Thanks all for trying to help us. :(